# Implementing GCS Blob fetching in Beam

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am currently trying to implement a `DoFn` `ProcessElement`, where I receive a `BlobId` as Input and pass along the Blob content as Output.
From what I have seen I could use Beams Filesystem and read the data via that.

Now I wonder especially in the context of DataFlow, if such code/class already exists (`TextIO.read` seems to do something similar).

Bonus points for a method which does not blow up Java HEAP.

Comment: Can you share a value of your blobId (without confidential value)?

Comment: In order to understand your process:you receive a `BlobId`, read from it and save its content in another file as the output. Is this correct?

Comment: Not quite, I receive a `BlobId`, read from it and pass it along to the pipeline/next `PTransform`. Question now is how to "read" and "pass along" in an efficient way.